# css div formatting and alignment

Tags: html, css

How do I align as so that the sidebar and picture section run alongside the main content area with NO white spaces

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykc1wyx8/)

```
<div id="page-container">
    <div id="mainnavigationarea">
        <p>Main Navigation</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rosaheadersection">
        <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rosapicturesection">
        <p>Picture Section</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rosachiefcontent">
        <p>Main Area. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rosasidebar-a">
        <p>Sidebar.Sidebar,Sidebar, Sidebar SidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rosafooter">
        <p>footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you just want picture select to be left

Comment: re-write your question more clearly for others to understand your question well

Comment: @baros i got answer but i need to check my answer is right so exactally tell whats your problem

Comment: I am a newbie to CSS and would like the picture section and sidebar to be right of main content area.  However I do not like the white space above and below the main content area and between sidebar and picture section

Comment: Where's your CSS? We can't help you if you haven't tried anything. (My apologies, I saw your fiddle. It's commonplace to post CSS with the HTML.)

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your main content and the sidebar content in their own `div` container and set that container to `float:left`. To remove the whitespace you need to remove the natural `margin` that's added to `p` tags.

**HTML**

```
<div id="page-container">
   <div id="mainnavigationarea">
      <p>Main Navigation</p>
   </div>
   <div id="rosaheadersection">
      <p>SM Tool</p>
   </div>
   <div class="left-container">
      <div id="rosachiefcontent">
         <p>Main Area. This sets the definition titles (our individual nav item containers) to float left, which stacks them left to right, instead of one under the other. Main Area. This sets the definition titles (our individual nav item containers) to float left, which stacks them left to right, instead of one under the other. Main Area. This sets the definition titles (our individual nav item containers) to float left, which stacks them left to right, instead of one under the other.</p>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="right-container">

      <div id="rosapicturesection">
         <p>Picture Section</p>
      </div>
      <div id="rosasidebar-a">
         <p>Sidebar.Sidebar,Sidebar, Sidebar SidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebar</p>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div id="rosafooter">
      <p>footer</p>
   </div>        
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p{
    margin: 0;
}

.left-container{
    float: left;
    width:980px;
}

.right-container{
    float: left;
    width: 280px;

}


#rosafooter {
    clear: both;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #3e5667;
    border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
    padding: 13px 25px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
#mainnavigationarea {
    height: 150px;
    background: #999;
}
#rosaheadersection {
    height: 150px;
    background: #7ac0da;
}
#rosapicturesection {
    height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 280px;
}
#rosasidebar-a {
    width: 280px;
    background:#3e5667
}
#rosachiefcontent h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#rosachiefcontent p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 50px;
}
#rosachiefcontent {
    clear: both;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-right: 280px;
    background:#a6dbed;
    width:980px;
    vertical-align:top
}
#page-container {
    width: 1260px;
    margin: auto;
    background:#fff
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ykc1wyx8/1/)

Comment: Thanks alot. This sorted it.

Comment: @baros no problem. Glad to help. Can you check this off as resolved?